# method called in document.m on closing of document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, nsdocument

i use `- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController` to see when a document has been loaded in a document based application. But what method should I use to see when a document is beeing closed? i would like to save the content of a textbox to the NSUserDefaults but i am unable to find a method that is called whenever the document is closing. i searched the web and also trough the methods that appear as hint in xcode but without luck! any help appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I observe `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` and override the `[NSDocument close]` method to perform document clean-up (`[NSDocument close]` isn't called when the app terminates!)

MyDocument.h:

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument
{
    BOOL _cleanedUp;    // BOOL to avoid over-cleaning up
    ...
}

@end
```

MyDocument.m:

```
// Private Methods
@implementation MyDocument ()

- (void)_cleanup;

@end

@implementation MyDocument

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _cleanedUp = NO;

        // Observe NSApplication close notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(_cleanup)
                                                     name:NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    // I'm using ARC so there is nothing else to do here
}

- (void)_cleanup
{
    if (!_cleanedUp)
    {
        _cleanedUp = YES;
        logdbg(@"Cleaning-up");

        // Do my clean-up
    }
}

- (void)close
{
    logdbg(@"Closing");

    [self _cleanup];

    [super close];
}
```

Comment: thanks, what do you mean "isnt called when the app terminates"? is there no native method to execute something on closing of a document?!?!

Comment: Yes, and that is `[NSDocument close]`, but as I say if the user just quits the app it isn't called (for some reason), which is unsatisfactory for my needs.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for your comment! this instad is called everytime when a document is closed and when the application is closed.. right?

Comment: Does this break state restoration? If I have some documents open and quit your app on Lion or Mountain Lion, will those documents still be reopened the next time I launch your app?

Comment: No I don't see why it would; it's for cleaning up document resources (in my case closing a database).

Comment: I meant responding to `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` by closing all the documents. Is state restoration still able to record the set of open documents at quit, either by doing that before you get notified and close them all or by them still being “open enough” (in whatever way it needs them to be) when the state-save happens?

Comment: As I say, I don't see why, as the document isn't closed in response to the notification; it's just used to clean-up without changing the document status.  However I can't say that I've explicitly tested it.

Comment: `- (void)close`: '*This method may not always be called.*'.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/close